# Remove the last "," from the string list without the help of Substring and str.Length - 1 (C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

Consider the below code snippet

```
string src = "ibm,tcs";

string dest = src.Split(',').Select(i => i + "();,").ToArray().Aggregate((s, i) => s + i);

dest = dest.Substring(0, dest.Length - 1);
```

What I am doing is that, the Source string(src here) will have the string list in comma separated way.

The final output will be: `ibm();,tcs();`

As we can make out that, my program is doing so.

But I am taking the help of `dest.Substring(0, dest.Length - 1);` for eliminating the last  `","` that I am building in the  Select Extension method.

I don't like this approach of mine.

Is there any other beautiful / elegant way of doing so? I am sure that someone will definitely approach in a better way :)

Also I will be happy if I get a solution using Lambda & Extension Method.

I am using C# 3.0 and dot net framework 3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `string.Join` instead of `Aggregate`, and don't include the comma in the Select clause:

```
string dest = string.Join(",", src.Split(',')
                                  .Select(i => i + "();")
                                  .ToArray());
```

In .NET 4 you wouldn't even need the `ToArray()` call (as extra overloads have been added to `string.Join`).

Or, as a completely alternative approach:

```
string dest = src.Replace(",", "();,") + "();";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string dest = string.Join(",", src.Split(',').Select(i => i + "();").ToArray());
```

or

```
string dest = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(src.Split(','), s => s + "();"));
```